# What is the best way to create a watchable dict

Tags: python, angularjs, dictionary, wxpython

I am currently creating a library to allow for a watchable dict to be used by the GUI https://github.com/jackburridge/pywatch, the intention is that like AngularJS the watchable object (in Angulars case $scope) can be treated like any other dict (object in Angular)

I currently have a watchable dictionary structure like this:

```
class Watcher:
def __init__(self, watch_object, item):
    self.watch_object = watch_object
    self.item = item
    self.listeners = []

def bind(self, callback):
    self.listeners.append(callback)

def notify(self):
    for listener in self.listeners:
        try:
            listener()
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(traceback.format_exc())

def get_value(self):
    return self.watch_object[self.item]

def set_value(self, value):
    self.watch_object[self.item] = value


class WatchableDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, seq=None, **kwargs):
        self.watchers = {}
        dict.__init__(self)

    def __setitem__(self, item, new_value):
        new_b = item in self
        old_value = self[item] if item in self else None
        dict.__setitem__(self, item, new_value)
        if new_b:
            if old_value != new_value:
                self.watchers[item].notify()
        else:
            self.watchers[item] = Watcher(self, item)

    def get_watcher(self, name):
        if name in self.watchers:
            return self.watchers[name]
        return None
```

Then someone can get a value from the dict to watch it using the `get_watcher` method. This currently works quite well but I'm wondering if there is a better approach for when I add additional features like nested dictionaries and lists

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do something along these lines some time ago. You can look at it at https://github.com/petrblahos/modellerkit, especially step07. My idea was to allow only immutable values in a container (I didn't use a dict but a class as a container). Then whenever someone called container_object.watched_property = "new value", this would be detected by the watched_property's **set** method, and listeners could be notified.

So I really ended up with the situation where I called

```
my_model.operation_list.append(Operation(10, 2123, datetime.datetime.now())
```

and my listview would be automatically updated, the label with the item count as well.

I believe you can simply clone the repo and run the examples to see how it works. I even use it in a project or 2. But I feel this approach somehow suits better to java then to python.